# How to apply a Gaussian radial basis function kernel PCA to nonlinear data?

Tags: pca, python, scikit-learn, kernel-trick

I have an assignment to implement a Gaussian *radial basis function*-kernel principal component analysis (RBF-kernel PCA) and have some challenges here. It would be great if someone could point me to the right direction because I am obviously doing something wrong here.

So, when I understand correctly, the RBF kernel is implemented like this:

$$K(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j) = \mathrm{exp}\left(- \gamma \|\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j\|^{2}_{2} \right)=\mathrm{exp}\left(- \frac{\|\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j\|^{2}_{2}}{2\sigma^2} \right),$$

where $\|\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j\|^{2}_{2} = \sum_j(x_{ik} - x_{jk})^2$ is the squared Euclidean distance between two data points, $\mathbf{x}_i$ and $\mathbf{x}_j$, and $\gamma$ is a free parameter $\gamma = \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$. The $\sigma^2$ can be chosen as the variance of the Euclidean distances between all pairs of data points.

To compare my approach to scikit-learn's implementation, I created a simple nonlinear dataset:

#### Example dataset

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
X, y = make_moons(n_samples=100, random_state=123)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

plt.scatter(X[y==0, 0], X[y==0, 1], color='red')
plt.scatter(X[y==1, 0], X[y==1, 1], color='blue')

plt.title('A nonlinear 2Ddataset')
plt.ylabel('y coordinate')
plt.xlabel('x coordinate')
```

[image]

#### scikit-learn RBF Kernel PCA

When I used the scikit-learn implementation for dimensionality reduction onto 1 component axis, the classes separate quite nicely.

```
scikit_kpca = KernelPCA(n_components=1, kernel='rbf', gamma=15)
X_skernpca = scikit_kpca.fit_transform(X)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.scatter(X_skernpca[y==0, 0], np.zeros((50,1)), color='red', alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(X_skernpca[y==1, 0], np.zeros((50,1)), color='blue', alpha=0.5)

plt.title('First component after RBF Kernel PCA')
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### My approach

Somehow, I am not able to reproduce those results. From what I understand, I have to compute all pairwise distances in order to compute the kernel. Then center the Kernel and extract the eigenvector that corresponds to the largest eigenvalue. This is what I have done so far:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import KernelCenterer
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from scipy import exp


# pdist to calculate the squared Euclidean distances for every pair of points
# in the 100x2 dimensional dataset.
sq_dists = pdist(X, 'sqeuclidean')

# Variance of the Euclidean distance between all pairs of data points.
variance = np.var(sq_dists)

# squareform to converts the pairwise distances into a symmetric 100x100 matrix
mat_sq_dists = squareform(sq_dists)

# set the gamma parameter equal to the one I used in scikit-learn KernelPCA
gamma = 15

# Compute the 100x100 kernel matrix
K = exp(gamma * mat_sq_dists)

# Center the kernel matrix
kern_cent = KernelCenterer()
K = kern_cent.fit_transform(K)

# Get the eigenvector with largest eigenvalue
eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eig(K)
eigvals, eigvecs = zip(*sorted(zip(eigvals, eigvecs), reverse=True))
X_pc1 = eigvecs[0]
```

[image]

## Edit

Thanks a lot to @Kirill ! He found my mistakes and the problem is solved now! Here is the correct version for future reference:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import KernelCenterer
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from scipy import exp
from scipy.linalg import eigh


# pdist to calculate the squared Euclidean distances for every pair of points
# in the 100x2 dimensional dataset.
sq_dists = pdist(X, 'sqeuclidean')

# Variance of the Euclidean distance between all pairs of data points.
variance = np.var(sq_dists)

# squareform to converts the pairwise distances into a symmetric 100x100 matrix
mat_sq_dists = squareform(sq_dists)

# set the gamma parameter equal to the one I used in scikit-learn KernelPCA
gamma = 15

# Compute the 100x100 kernel matrix
K = exp(-gamma * mat_sq_dists)

# Center the kernel matrix
kern_cent = KernelCenterer()
K = kern_cent.fit_transform(K)

# Get eigenvalues in ascending order with corresponding 
# eigenvectors from the symmetric matrix
eigvals, eigvecs = eigh(K)

# Get the eigenvectors that corresponds to the highest eigenvalue
X_pc1 = eigvecs[:,-1]
```

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, and I haven't run your code, but in `exp(gamma * mat_sq_dists)`, is the *sign* of `gamma` correct? Shouldn't it be $-15$ instead of $15$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have actually tried both variants... The equation is written differently e.g., http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex8/ex8.html like you said, and the other way around on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel

Comment: I don't mean in the equation. In your code, if `gamma` is positive, then the kernel tends to infinity as two points tend away from each other, which is the opposite of what I would expect, i.e., $\exp(15\|x_1-x_2\|^2)\to\infty$ instead of $\to0$.

Comment: @Kirill is right, it should be minus `gamma`.

Comment: @MarcClaesen Yes, he was right. I played with different lambdas (positive and negative) but the biggest problem was probably that I selected the first eigenvector wrongly. I selected the first row of the eigenvector matrix instead of the first column. Thanks to Kirill the problem is solved now :) Thanks everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem seems to be that the sign of `gamma` is wrong (it should be negative: $-15$, as in the definition of the kernel, not as in your code). Alternatively, use `exp(-gamma * mat_sq_dists)`.

The second problem is that you clobber the eigenvectors with your invocation of `zip`'s when you sort the list. The $i$-th eigenvector is `eigvecs[:,i]`, not `eigvecs[i,:]`, according to `scipy.linalg.eigh` (also: you should prefer `eigh` to `eig` because you have a symmetric real matrix).

Replace

```
< gamma = 15
> gamma = -15
```

and (to get ordered, real eigenvalues)

```
< eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eig(K)
> eigvals, eigvecs = scipy.linalg.eigh(K)
```

and

```
< eigvals, eigvecs = zip(*sorted(zip(eigvals, eigvecs), reverse=True))
< X_pc1 = eigvecs[0]
> X_pc1 = eigvecs[:,99]
```

Finally, you can examine `scikit-learn`'s own implementation [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/kernel_pca.py).

Comment: Thanks you so much! I really really appreciate it! It was such a frustrating problem and I am so happy that this is solved now thanks to you! I added the correct solution add the bottom of my OP. Thousand thanks!

Comment: @SebastianRaschka You're welcome.